# SQL LIKE seems not work like i think it should

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, shopware6

I have an SELECT statement that has a huge number of left join and I want to filter some out.

When I check how many records i have in total and subtract the records with my LIKE statements, I should get the amount that is not affected by my restrictions.

But when I negate my restriction to get the ones I didn't affect, I get an different number than calculated.

SQL without restrictions (Record count: 13.251.981)

```
SELECT p.product_number
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_category pc on p.id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_category_tree pct on p.id = pct.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_configurator_setting pcs on p.id = pcs.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_cross_selling pcs2 on p.id = pcs2.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_cross_selling_assigned_products pcsap on p.id = pcsap.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_cross_selling_translation pcst on pcs2.id = pcst.product_cross_selling_id
LEFT JOIN product_custom_field_set pcfs on p.id = pcfs.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_media pm on p.id = pm.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_option po on p.id = po.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_price pp on p.id = pp.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_property pp2 on p.id = pp2.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_review pr on p.id = pr.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_search_keyword psk on p.id = psk.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_tag pt on p.id = pt.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_translation pt2 on p.id = pt2.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_visibility pv on p.id = pv.product_id
```

With restriction (Record count: 9.285.545)

```
WHERE p.product_number NOT LIKE 'SW%'
  AND p.product_number NOT LIKE '%.%'
  AND pt2.name NOT LIKE '%Gutschein'
  AND pt2.name NOT LIKE '%Test%'
```

With negated restriction (Record count: 100.851)

```
WHERE p.product_number LIKE 'SW%'
   OR p.product_number LIKE '%.%'
   OR pt2.name LIKE '%Gutschein'
   OR pt2.name LIKE '%Test%';
```

From my calculations i should get 3.966.436 records that don't get affected. (13.251.981 - 9.285.545 = 3.966.436)

But instead I get 100.851

How is that possible?

Comment: how can a product not have a category?   How can it not have a price? Too many left joins is a code smell

Comment: Consider nulls. If you don't know what I mean, run this - `declare @t table (A varchar(10)); insert into @T(A) values (null); select * from @t; select * from @t where A like '%.%'; select * from @t where A not like '%.%';`

Comment: (Apologies, example is using some SQL Server features but a similar example should be possible to set up in mysql also, and the actual `LIKE` behaviour should be the same)

Comment: *How is that possible?* If any value (p.product_number or pt2.name) checked in WHERE is NULL then neither restricted not negatively restricted condition will return this row. PS. The conditions by `pt2.name` must be placed into ON condition, not into WHERE. Now they converts all above joins to INNER ones.

Comment: @MitchWheat
What makes you think that this is the case according to the SQL?
Also yes Shopware supports not selecting a category, but i dont know how that plays out tbh. (Probably for testing purpose)

Comment: Thanks for all the help here, but i found out my question should have been different, but realised that like 3hours later...
Sry for that

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was actually this WHERE:
WHERE p.product_number < 'SW'